# UIPopoverController backgroundColor back to default after rotation on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

When setting `backgroundColor` to `[UIColor blackColor]` to a `UIPopoverController` everything is fine and presents correctly on iOS7 and iOS8.

I present it via

```
    [aPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                     animated:YES];
```

After a device rotation, the popover `backgroundColor` is reset to default color (white in this case).

**This does not happend in iOS 7. Only on iOS 8**

I have already tried with

```
- (void)presentPopoverFromRect:(CGRect)rect 
                        inView:(UIView *)view 
      permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections 
                      animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

and a repositioning using `UIPopoverControllerDelegate` and the same problem occurs.

**Last information :** I had this problem only when displaying the popover on a UINavigationBar but not when presenting it on a regular `UIView` or any `UIButton`.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior. Have any luck finding the solution to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also had such problem with popover on iOS8. Besides rotation the background colour was reset when popover changed its size (e.g. when keyboard shows up to edit some text field in the popover).
The key observation is that the issue usually happens with popovers that have its arrow on the very content's edge (and this is the case when presenting popover from `UIBarButtonItem` of full screen view controller).
Hence my workaround was to modify `sourceRect` just enough for the popover's arrow to move away from its corner. For example in my particular case I had a bar button item with custom 33x33 view (which was used as `sourceView`) and the issue was fixed by setting `sourceRect` to `{20, 30, 0, 0}` instead of custom view's bounds (though I suppose the exact required offset may depend on popover's size).

Comment: I found that if the view is positioned so the arrow is attached to the bubble hard left or right - I'm trying to describe this to avoid posting an image link that will probably expire - then this problem is encountered. E.g. the arrow is right at the edge and there is no rounded corner.
Offsetting this by just one pixel away from the edge fixed it for me:

`sourceRect = CGRectOffset(buttonRect, -1, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

**For iOS 8.2 (xcode 6.2)** : i have problem while open keyboard, popovercontroller becomes white. and after keyboard disappears it is also same as white background.

i use following code to resolve my issue.

```
[objPopovercontroller presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectOffset(CGRectMake(SCREEN_WIDTH-40, 60, 0, 0), -1, 0) 
                                      inView:self.view 
                    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp 
                                    animated:YES]; 

// SCREEN_WIDTH = (IS_IPAD?1024:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem in iOS 9.1. Offsetting the source rect was a good observation and workaround but for me it didn't seem to have an effect until the offset reached 16 or so, which meant the arrow looked somewhat mis-placed.

To avoid this, in the end I used [GIKPopoverBackgroundView](https://github.com/GiK/GIKPopoverBackgroundView) to provide a custom background view (`UIPopoverBackgroundView`). I extracted the relevant popover background images from UIKit (see [1] below) to get the same popover shape as iOS 9 and modified their colour to suit my needs.

Heavy-handed, and a bit fiddly setting up the cap insets for the images, but it did the trick.

[1] Use [cartool](https://github.com/steventroughtonsmith/cartool) to get _UIPopoverViewBlurMaskBackground* from  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Artwork.bundle/Assets.car